# How to present a map inside one my app's views?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, location, mapkit

One of my app's functions is to pinpoint the user's current location.  It automatically requests current location and gets an address.  However this is frequently not accurate enough.

I would prefer the app to still automatically request location and address, but when the user taps a button to proceed, present a map with an indication of estimated current location in the screen center, and allow the user to drag the map around to refine a more precise location.

I'm able to programmatically hand the user off to the Map app with a current location indicator, but I can't figure out how to keep the user in my app and present a map UX optimized only for refining current location (no other features beyond zoom and drag).

I have used some apps that do this, but I cannot find any guidance on how to accomplish it myself.  Can anyone point the way?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to user the MapKit, position the user on it and set the span in a way that zoom is very close (like 0.0001):

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0001, 0.0001)

let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, span)
map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: Andreza, thanks -- but I have no trouble configuring the map's attributes.  I am instead trying to display the map within my app rather than handing the user off to the iPhone's Map app.  Refining the location is one of many steps in the workflow and I want to keep the user in a consistent experience.

Comment: But what I mentioned is not to redirect your user to the iPhone maps, but to add a map to your app (a MapView) and configure it in a way that you can do what you wish... That solution wouldn't help?

Comment: After cleaning up my code it seems to still be opening the Maps app.  I have other apps with similar code that presents the map within the MKMapView.  I will try to find out why and post the reasons.

Comment: Ok, let me tell you step by step what needs to be done and you check your code...
1 - On your storyboard, on the ViewController you want the map to appear, you add a Map Kit View.
2 - Create an outlet for that map view n your view controller

Comment: 3 - Add the delegate MKMapViewDelegate to your view controller and to the outlet on ViewDidLoad
4 - Declare a var/let to CLLocationManager so you can ask the permission to get the user's location and request location
5 - Add the delegate CLLocationManagerDelegate to your view controller and the var/let that you created

Comment: 6 - On "locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])", show user location (self.map.showsUserLocation = true) and center the user on the map :
let currentSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0,0001, 0,0001)
let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locations.last.coordinate, currentSpan)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

I think it's pretty much it. Check it out.